# Necesito que las imagens tengan diferente div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando que las etiquetas img tengas distintas id. Cuando se suben imagenes que ambas tengan distintas ids pero lo que pasa es que ambas tienen el mismo id.

```
   if (input.files) {
        var files = input.files;
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) { 
            var image = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {

                 src_imagenagregada = event.target.result;
                 $("#imagenes").append("<img id='image"+i+"' width='60' height='60' src='"+src_imagenagregada+"'>");

            }

             reader.readAsDataURL(image);


        }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Has pensado en hacer eso en el backend? Te lo pregunto en un comentario, porque tambien me tope con el problema hace un tiempo y decidi hacerlo en PHP, y resulto mucho mejor.

Comment: Necesito que el usuario pueda ver el preview de la imagen sin tener que guardarla. Con php tendría que guardar y después acceder a la imagen o estoy equivocado?

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, y pues por eso solo te preguntaba. Me parece una buena pregunta y por eso te di un voto, para que resalte un poco mas y puedas obtener un buena respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es contar en tu contenedor `#imagenes` cuantas etiquetas `img` tienes y sumarle 1, ejemplo:

```
for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
  var image = files[i];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    src_imagenagregada = event.target.result;
    $("#imagenes").append("<img id='image" + ($('#imagenes > img').length + 1) + "' width='60' height='60' src='" + src_imagenagregada + "'>");
  }
}
```

Saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede aquí es que las imágenes se despliegan una vez terminado el ciclo `for` y la variable `i` ya quedo en un valor fijo, hay varias formas de solucionar esto pero la mas sencilla es agregar una variable para usar como indizador por ejemplo:

```
var indizador = 0;
for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) { 
            var image = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {

                 src_imagenagregada = event.target.result;
                 $("#imagenes").append("<img id='image"+indizador +"' width='60' height='60' src='"+src_imagenagregada+"'>");
                 indizador++

            }

             reader.readAsDataURL(image);


        }
```